# execlp time doesn't show anything

Tags: c, linux, time, terminal, exec

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 
   execlp("time", "time", NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

Nevertheless, if I add an argument to time like ls, it does work:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 
   execlp("time", "time", "ls", NULL);

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
LICENCIA                main.c                  msh                     parser.y                prueba.c                scanner.o               y.tab.h
Makefile                main.o                  parser.o                prueba                  scanner.l               tempCodeRunnerFile.c
        0,00 real         0,00 user         0,00 sys
```

Any idea?

Comment: What would you expect it to time if you are not providing a command to time? Or are you saying that you do not see the error message that says a program to run is missing printed to standard error? I can see it with your code.

Comment: in the linux terminal if you type `time` it shows you the shell and child processes times, that's what I want but from a c program

Comment: @miguelrr_11 The `time` you use in your shell is likely a built-in command of that shell, not the actual `time` program somewhere in your `PATH` (which is what `execlp` will call).

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/223221/using-the-built-in-time-command-in-bash-rather-than-the-external-command

Answer (score 1):

This works as expected. `execlp("time", "time", NULL);` is equivalent to executing `/usr/bin/time` (assuming that is what it resolves to; it could be different environments different from mine), and executing `/usr/bin/time` (again on my system, macOS 10.14.6) with no arguments does not print anything. I suppose other implementations of the `time` utility could print a message that no command to time was given and/or exit with an error code.

In contrast, `execlp("time", "time", "ls", NULL);` is equivalent to executing `/usr/bin/time ls`, in which case the `time` program executes `ls` and reports its times.

> in the linux terminal if you type time it shows you the shell and child processes times…

When you type `time` in a command-line shell, it executes the shell’s built-in `time` function, not the system `time` program. To reproduce this using `execlp`, you must use `execlp` to start a shell, not `time`, and you must pass the shell arguments to give it a `time` command to execute.